# Why do i get FailedToParse while i run my server on mongodb atlas database?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

When I run my server from localhost database , I get the results that I want. But whenever i run my server from mongoDb atlas, i get an error that says "FailedToParse" .

My api code is `

```
const id = req.params.userId
const conversations = await Conversation.aggregate([
  { $match : { members : id } },
  {
    $lookup:
    {
      from : "messages",
      localField : "_id",
      foreignField : "conversationId",
      as: "last_message",
               "pipeline": 
        [  
            { "$sort": { "_id": -1 } },
            { "$limit": 1 }
        ]
      }
  },
  { "$addFields": {
      "last_message": { "$arrayElemAt": [ "$last_message", 0 ] }
    }
  }
]);

console.log('conversations', conversations);

res.status(200).send(conversations) `
```

And I got this result `

```
"operationTime": "7029823666309300225",

"ok": 0,
"code": 9,
"codeName": "FailedToParse",
"$clusterTime": {
    "clusterTime": "7029823666309300225",
    "signature": {
        "hash": "6PEpXcdz8JQSej0XlAF+hIJ/g1Q=",
        "keyId": "6975126282837164033"
    }
},
"name": "MongoError"
```

`

Comment: Is the driver version compatible with the Atlas version?

Comment: how do i cheque server version of mongoDB atlas ?

Comment: It should be listed under each cluster on the project page